# MVC5 'link login' to external site losing the current identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, owin

I'm using an MVC system where I use OWIN authentication, implementing my own IUserStore/etc and that all works great.  I'm not looking into linking my logins with external logins, and i'm having trouble using the code that comes with MVC5.  In particular:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult LinkLogin(string provider)
        {
            // Request a redirect to the external login provider to link a login for the current user
            return new ChallengeResult(provider, Url.Action("LinkLoginCallback", "Manage",), User.Identity.GetUserId());
        }
```

and

```
public class ChallengeResult : HttpUnauthorizedResult
    {
        // Used for XSRF protection when adding external logins
        internal const string XsrfKey = "XsrfId";
        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri)
            : this(provider, redirectUri, null)
        {
        }

        public ChallengeResult(string provider, string redirectUri, string userId)
        {
            LoginProvider = provider;
            RedirectUri = redirectUri;
            UserId = userId;
        }

        public string LoginProvider { get; set; }
        public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
            var properties = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = RedirectUri };
            if (UserId != null)
            {
                properties.Dictionary[XsrfKey] = UserId;
            }

            Container.GetInstance<Microsoft.Owin.Security.IAuthenticationManager>().Challenge(properties, LoginProvider);
        }
    }
```

I have only changed the challenge result so that it uses my structuremap DI instead of GetOwinContext for the authenticationmanager.  The problem is that i have all of my controllers set with a [CustomAuthorize] attribute, and when i reach the LinkLogin method, it works fine.  The context.user.identity variable is of AuthenticationType 'ApplicationCookie', which is good and what i want.
However when it goes through the challegeresult part of 'LinkLogin', i hit my CustomAuthorize code again and now the user is no longer the same.  The Context.User.Identity variable is now of AuthenticationType 'Negotiate', and it has my windows login as the username instead.
This doesn't work with my application at all, and i end up getting a 403 error because it can't resolve that user to the correct Cookie user.

Is there something that i'm doing wrong here?  I've tried to put AllowAnonymous above LinkLogin, but that doesn't seem to help at all.  Not sure if i need to modify ChallengeResult somehow to fit my needs better.  Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out i was passing a null value as the 'provider' by accident.  once i fixed that, it worked correctly